# dotnet - how to know if we are using .net/.net core/asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

I want to use `.NET Core 5` in my project.

myProj.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Authentication\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Is it `.NET Core 5` project?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks .NET Core is renamed to .NET 5 and later.

Comment: You already do use .Net core 5. The property targetframework says net5.0. And this is what Microsoft says : ".NET 5.0 is the next major release of .NET Core following 3.1".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five